# Add class to current post in query_post

Tags: categories, query-posts

I have a query like this;

```
                        <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
                    <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
                        $cat = $category->cat_ID; }
                        query_posts('orderby=date&cat=' . $cat . '&order=desc&posts_per_page=-1'); 
                    ?>
```

It grabs all the posts from the current category.

What i then do with this information is create a list of all the thumbnails associated with those posts.

What i would like to do is highlight in some way, the current post. (through a class or something), something that is obviously done automatically normally.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the main current post id into a variable and compare it in the loop with the current post id; example:

```
<?php $this_post = $post->ID; ?>
  <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>                     
  <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {                         
  $cat = $category->cat_ID; 
  }                         
query_posts('orderby=date&cat=' . $cat . '&order=desc&posts_per_page=-1');  
while( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <span<?php if( $this_post == $post->ID ) { echo ' class="current"'; } ?>>
   /*output of your posts here*/
  </span>
<?php endwhile;                    
?>
```

Comment: Perfect! What would i do without you guys?!